# Can't resolve a simple equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck with an equation I've been trying to solve for a while in different ways. Tried searching on the internet about the properties of arccosh (or cosh-1) and cosh but still couldn't find the way. I get the feeling the solution to this is going to be easy and stupid, but I feel I've been going in circles here.

I need to solve it by hand because I will need to solve this kind of equation in an exam.

[This is the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxuxX.png)

It should be solvable, but in case it's not, I need to say that I've got this after a simplification, in which I don't think I made any mistakes but just in case here is the simplification I made:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7iE.png)

Please note that for U1 and U2 all the variables are unknown but they remain the same for these two cases, except Z. That's why I could simplify it in this way.

In case someone is wondering, this is a problem about sea waves. I was given the speed of particles in a given place (at 2 different depths) and I'm using Airy's linear theory to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
$$\frac{0.34}{0.44} = \frac{cosh(\frac{90\pi}{x})}{cosh(\frac{110\pi}{x})}$$

Edit2:
I suppose I could solve it using iterations, but I will need to do it several times during the exam and I'd rather know if there is a better way to solve it.

Comment: Please use MathJax (see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and refrain from posting links to pictures. It isn't loading for me.

Comment: In what way does posting here count as "solve it by hand"?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Edited with the formula, thanks for the idea

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I think it's *your* hands rather than OP's, but it's still hands. :)

Comment: It "reduces" to solving a polynomial of degree $10$, which you're not going to do by anyone's hand.

Comment: @JohnHughes Well, it's not like I'm in the exam now, I'm studying and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Understood, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the equation, you need to find the zero of
$$f(x)=34 \cosh \left(\frac{110 \pi }{x}\right)-44 \cosh \left(\frac{90 \pi }{x}\right)$$ If you try to plot it, you will notice that the fnction varies extremely fast and it is difficult to locate where is more or less the root.

So, consider instead
$$g(x)=\log \left(34 \cosh \left(\frac{110 \pi }{x}\right)\right)-\log \left(44 \cosh
   \left(\frac{90 \pi }{x}\right)\right)$$ which is better conditioned (looking more or less like an hyperbola) and, graphing, you will see that there is a root close to $x=200$.

At this point, using $x_0=200$, apply Newton method with 
$$g'(x)=\frac{90 \pi  \tanh \left(\frac{90 \pi }{x}\right)}{x^2}-\frac{110 \pi  \tanh
   \left(\frac{110 \pi }{x}\right)}{x^2}$$ You will then get the following iterates :
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 200.0000000 \\
 1 & 216.3366146 \\
 2 & 217.6456022 \\
 3 & 217.6530075 \\
 4 & 217.6530077
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution  for ten significant figures.

If you want a shortcut, expand $f(x)$ as a Taylor series for large values of $x$. This would give
$$f(x)=-10+\frac{27500 \pi ^2}{x^2}+\frac{261387500 \pi ^4}{3
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ and, ignoring the higher order terms, this would give a quadratic in $\frac 1 {x^2}$ for which the solution is 
$$x^2=\frac{25}{3} \left(165+\sqrt{152691}\right) \pi ^2$$ which makes $x\approx 213.797$

Comment: Wow! That's amazing thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. I never would have thought of some of the steps you did there PS: I gave you an upvote but I'm new so they won't count it. Thanks again anyway